# Is it possible to call a view from settings?

Tags: django, django-views, circular-dependency

I am doing an extension for Django and I want to let the user indicate a view in the settings file.

But if the user include a call to a view as a constant in the setting file, a circular dependency is produced because the view uses django.http that uses the SECRET_KEY from settings:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Any way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "call" here? Give an example.

Comment: I want that the view of my extension to return what the user wants by a settings variable set up by the user in the settings file: return setting('NOT_AUTHORISED_USER', default=HttpResponseForbidden())

Comment: therefore the user can choose between render a template, a custom httpresponse, a redirect...

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean let the user indicate a view in the settings file?
Do you mean something like:
`SOME_VIEW = yourapp.views.SomeView`
Or you need something else?

Comment: @petkostas yes, that's it. The problem is that when django app starts to load the settings, it reads the "import yourapp.views" or if you prefer "from yourapp.views import SomeView" and raises the error mentioned above because the view file has: from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define in your settings the path of your view as a string:

```
MY_VIEW = 'myapp.views.SomeView'
```

Then import that where you needed it (not in settings):

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_by_path
my_view = import_by_path(settings.MY_VIEW)
```

Then you can use my_view as you would if you were using:

```
from myapp.views import SomeView
```

- import_by_path is available since 1.6